# find the largest value in 2d dictionary wrt to the key

Tags: python

I have data in following form:

```
key, time_bin, count
abc, 1, 200
abc, 2,230
abc1,1,300
abc1,2,180
abc2,1, 300
abc2,2, 800
```

So each of the key has same number of time_bin..

I want to find the following..
For each,time bin which are the top n keys based on count..

So, in the example above.. lets say I want to find out.. what are the top 2 keys for each time bin?
So..answer is

```
1=> [{"abc1",300},{"abc2":300}]
2=> ({"abc2":800},{"abc":230}]
```

WHat is a good way to solve this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `2=> ({"abc2":800},{"abc":230}]`?

Comment: @unutbu: that is certainly what I got..

Comment: I'd move it to DB, where you can easily do Group by time_bin, Order by Count Desc, limit / top n. . .

Comment: @unutbu: yes.. sorry. my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import csv

counts = defaultdict(Counter)

with open(somefilename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # skip the header
    for row in reader:
        key, time_bin, count = row[0], int(row[1]), int(row[2])
        counts[time_bin][key] += count

for time_bin in counts:
    print '{}=> {}'.format(time_bin, counts[time_bin].most_common(2))
```

The `Counter.most_common()` method specifically is helpful here; it returns the top counts for a given set of counts, here collected per time bin.

The output format *almost* matches your example:

```
1=> [('abc1', 300), ('abc2', 300)]
2=> [('abc2', 800), ('abc', 230)]
```

because `.most_common()` returns a list of tuples, not dictionaries.

Comment: I usually use `DictReader` here, e.g. `reader = csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)` [...] `counts[row['time_bin']][row['key']] += int(row['count'])`.